# Phonegap jqm mixing local and server html files

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I would like to add some online pages to an application keep them up to date without releasing a new store version. For this I taught I could use jqm ajax navigation to load the external page. (I'm aware that might not be allowed for all platforms.)

I have set:

```
 $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
 $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
```

This seems to work but the problem is that all my href's and $.mobile.ChangePages would have to be changed to

```
<a href='http://mydomain.com/mypage.html'>link</a> 
$.mobile.changePage('http://mydomain.com/mypage.html');
```

in stead of

```
<a href='mypage.html'>link</a>
$.mobile.changePage('http://mydomain.com/mypage.html');
```

Is there a better way to load html pages locally and online using jqm ajax navigation?

Extra info:

- Phonegap/Cordova version 3.5.0
- jqm 1.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use method **[loadPage](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.loadPage/)** instead? It will load remote page (using **AJAX**, just like jQuery method load) into the **DOM**. Then you can easily use **changePage** to open loaded page.

It can be used to load external and internal content. It will not suffer cross-domain problems like **$.ajax** function. You only need to be careful when loading content into the **DOM**, if wanted page is large you will need to remove it from the **DOM** manually. That is only downside of this solution (I will show you an example if you want).

Plus you need to understand another thing. When using loadPage or changePage to load external content, be it load or remote **HTML** file, jQuery Mobile will load ONLY first **data-role="page"** div found in remote file. It will discard everything else. Including other pages.

If you want to load complete content then you should use jQuery method load, but be careful to load only **BODY** content, it can get messy if you load compete HTML page (including **HEAD**) into existing jQuery Mobile project.

Comment: I understand that it will only load the first page div. So I load my external pages and change my href's and changepage's to work with id's in stead of the xxxx.html.(or isn't this necessary?) And if the page is big use this.remove() in the pagehide.

Comment: You will load HTML file but when its loaded you will ref. to it using its page id (for example #ext-page). Any you are correct regarding .remove() on page hide. Finally someone who know how jQM works :)

Comment: I seem to have a problem when I navigate from the external page to a local page and then try to load the external page again. (I know I remove it but it should get reloaded everytime). I've added some code to my question.

Comment: Can you open new question? Add everything we done in this question. I will help you to find a correct solution, and this way other people will also see it.

Comment: new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062922/phonegap-jqm-navigation-between-local-and-external-page