# Phonegap jqm Ajax load an external page without changes base domain of the navigation

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm having an issue with the page changes... In phonegap it works once and on chrome it doesn't work.

This is the code I use to load an external page in the dom and open it. After moving away it get's removed from dom.

```
function changeToMypage() {
    $.mobile.loadPage('http://mydomain/mypage.html', {
        prefetch: "true"
    }).done(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage('#mypageid');
    });
}
$(document).on("pagehide", "#mypageid", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

On phonegap it works the first time I navigate to the external page but when I navigate to a local page and back to the external page it stops working.(Reloads the current page in stead) 
In chrome it never works. It seems to try and load file://indexpage.html#mypageid in the changepage
but this doesn't work because I'm using single page navigation.

I don't understand how the pageload appends the mypage.html to the dom to navigate to it with the pageid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery.mobile.navigate() solved my problem but this is a low level api method according to the [JQM docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.navigate/). Maybe someone could give some extra information why it works with this method and not with changepage?